# VUE: Using Global Variable for Imgs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuetify.js

1. The image is saved in firebase Data as a JPG
2. The image saved in The Global Variable of my Main.js in Vue
3. I have a component that is  on top of my
4. I am trying to pull my data from my Main.js and use it on my Client header

[Picture of my Main.js where the uploaded image is stored globally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q16cD.jpg)

```
<b-form inline>
          <router-link to ="/profilePage" class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 dropdownTxt">
            <img :src="ClientHeaderImage" id="smallProfileImg">&nbsp;&nbsp;</router-link>
          <b-dropdown id="ddown1__BV_toggle_1234" 
                      style="font-size:1.5em;"
                      text="Profile">
            <b-dropdown-item>
              <router-link to ="/jobFeedPage" class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" dropdownTxt>Internships</router-link></b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item>
              <router-link to ="/profilePage" class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 dropdownTxt">Profile</router-link></b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item>
              <router-link to ="/internHomePage" class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 dropdownTxt">Search</router-link></b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item>
              <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 dropdownTxt" @click="logout">Logout</button></b-dropdown-item>
```

```
 methods: {
data: function () {
  ClientHeaderImage: this.store.uploadedImage;
},
```

**This.store.uploadedImage** is pulling out my Firebase Image from Storage

If you take a look at the Console. This is what I see
[MY CONSOLE.LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgiUd.jpg)

can someone please help me on trying to display this onto my HTML Template

Comment: sorry the Third Line of this Post is
3. I have the Clientheader component that is on top of my ProfilePage Template